# HighCharts map without GoogleSpreadsheet

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking at the following tutorial:

http://www.highcharts.com/studies/world-map.htm

I am trying to add a map like this to my own site however I do not want to use Google Spreadsheet data. I want to specify the data myself via JavaScript.

Is there a way to use the HighCharts world map without Google SpreadSheet? All the examples that I find involving the HighCharts map takes data from Google Spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source, the part that populates the data is:

```
for (var i = 1; i < countryCodes.length; i++) {     
    if (shapes[countryCodes[i]]) {
        options.series[0].data.push({
            y : parseFloat(populationDensities[i]),
            name : countryNames[i],
            path : Highcharts.pathToArray(shapes[countryCodes[i]]),
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#FF7F00' // orange
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

`countryCodes`, `populationDensities` and `countryNames` come from the google spread sheet but it should be trivial to loop the countries you care about on your own.  Just remember that the `countryCode` must be defined in the shape object [here](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/world-map-shapes.js), the `populationDensity` is the numerical value for that country, and the `countryName` is the value displayed on the map.